# Url.Action route config style path

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to create a Url.Action link that redirects to a page with the format

```
.../Images/View/imageid
```

using RouteConfig. So far the only solution I've found is to setup the link like this

```
@Url.Action("View/" + image.ID, "Images")
```

The `new { imageid = image.ID }` version returns a url like `.../Images/Views?imageid=image.ID` which does not work when inserting the requested image into an email (and is visually unappealing).

**So my question: Is there a more semantically correct way to return a url with the format `.../Images/View/imageid` or am I already using the best possible method?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `@Url.RouteURl( string routename, object routevalues )` gives exactly the output I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

do something like below, assuming Images is your controller , views is your action.

```
 @Url.Action("Views", "Images", new RouteValueDictionary() {{"imageid", image.ID}})
```

and in your routeconfig.cs  have the below below as your first route

```
 routes.MapRoute(
             name: null,
             url: "{controller}/{action}/{imageid}",
             defaults: new { Controller = "Images", action = "Views" }

           );
```

I havent test this but it should be something along this way